# Kafka - set topic for compaction

Tags: apache-kafka

What it means to set some topic `for compaction`?

What are pros/cons if that is not done for a specific topic?

Just trying to understand terms and how it behaves.

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple log retention i.e log retention based out of time/size will not work for all cases. Definitely, this method proves to save you the space but it does not guarantee you the current state of the data.

Please allow me to explain this with a scenario.

Let us imagine we are having a stream of messages or logs with respect to a user in stackoverflow and you want to manage the state of the user. The key of the message is UserID and the value is the UserInformation(NickName,Address,Email,Telephone etc).

A user can change his nicknames as many times he want. Similarly, he can also change the Contact or any information. Log compaction will help you to retain the latest user based information by deleting or cleaning the redundant data. But, time based or size based retention may not give you a guarantee to retain the state of the user.

> Log compaction retains last known value it is a full snapshot of the
>   latest records it is useful for restoring state after a crash or
>   system failure for an in-memory service, a persistent data store, or
>   reloading a cache. It allows downstream consumers to restore their
>   state.

Hope this helps.